# how to process big file with comparison of each line in that file with remaining all lines in same file?

Tags: string-comparison, opencsv, file-processing

I have csv file with 5,00,000 records in it. Fields in csv file are as follows

No, Name, Address

Now i want to compare name and address from each record with name and address of all remaining records.
I was doing it in following way

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader firstbufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newFile(pathname)));
while ((line = firstbufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            lines.add(line);
        }
        firstbufferedReader.close();
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) 
        {
            csvReader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(lines.get(i)));
            csvReader = null;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < lines.size(); j++) 
            {

                    csvReader = new CSVReader(new StringReader(lines.get(j)));
                    csvReader = null;
                    application.linesToCompare(lines.get(i),lines.get(j));
            }
        }
```

linesToCompare Function will extract name and address from respective parameters and do comaprison. If i found records to be 80% matching(based on name and address) i am marking them as duplicates.
But my this approach is taking too much time to process that csv file.
I want a faster approach may be some kind of map reduce or anything.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is taking a long time because it looks like you are reading the file a huge amount of times.

You first read the file into the `lines` List, then for every entry you read it again, then inside that you read it *again*!.  Instead of doing this, read the file once into your `lines` array and then use that to compare the entries against each other.

Something like this might work for you:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
BufferedReader firstbufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(newFile(pathname)));
while ((line = firstbufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    lines.add(line);
}
firstbufferedReader.close();
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) 
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < lines.size(); j++) 
    {
        application.linesToCompare(lines.get(i),lines.get(j));
    }
}
```